Function properties in real variables, real analysis question
Are these properties of real variable functions simply defined as they are, or is there another explanation?
$(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$
$(fg)(x) = f(x)g(x)$
$(af)(x) = af(x)$

Summation, multiplication, and scalar multiplication of functions are simply defined by the formulas you wrote down. So, yes, these are defined this way.

They are simply defined this way!
